# What does ≺ represent?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I've been reading through Axiomatic Set Theory by Patrick Suppes and stumbled upon this symbol, ≺, on page 97. The definition reads as follows: *We now define in the expected manner the relation ≺ of having less power*. It then shows an example theorem stating to prove A ≺ A ∪ B, but I don't understand what the author means by having less power.

Comment: Since have the book, and many people do not, you could help us help you by giving the exact definition.

Comment: My guess would be $A < B$ is equivalent to "$A$ is a subset of $B$."

Comment: "Power" is sometimes used as a synonym for "cardinality".

Comment: All that is clear when taken out of context is that $\prec$ is generally used as a partial order or a strict partial order.  [See wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set).  In the case that they intend $\prec$ to be the strict partial order defined as $A\prec B\Leftrightarrow |A|<|B|$, then the statement $A\prec A\cup B$ is not true when $B\subseteq A$ or when $A$ is infinite in size.  It will however be true if it is not a strict partial order, i.e. $A\prec B\Leftrightarrow |A|\leq |B|$

Comment: This is a legitimate question and does not deserve to be closed. Specially not after less than an hour!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On page 94 it says:

[image]

I guess $A\approx C$ means that $A$ and $C$ have the same cardinality,
and so $A \preceq B$ means that there is an injection $A \to B$.

Then on page 97 it says:

[image]

It is clear that $A \prec B$ does not mean $A \subset B$.
Using the interpretation I gave above for $A \preceq B$, it probably means that the cardinality of $A$ is strictly less than the cardinality of $B$, in the sense that there is an injection $A \to B$ but not an injection $B \to A$.

"$A$ is a subset of $B$" is defined on page 22 and uses the standard notation $A \subseteq B$.

Comment: That is actually $A \approx C$ in the image.

Comment: @GEdgar, indeed! fixed , thanks.